# How do I get Apache Ignite persistence to work?

Tags: persistence, ignite

I have the following configuration for my embedded Ignite (v2.3) service (it will be a cluster eventually, but embedded is easier for development):

```
    val config = new IgniteConfiguration

    val dsConfig = new DataStorageConfiguration
    dsConfig.setStoragePath("ignitedb/storage")
    dsConfig.setWalPath("ignitedb/wal")
    dsConfig.setWalArchivePath("ignitedb/wal/archive")
    dsConfig.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
    config.setDataStorageConfiguration(dsConfig)

    Ignition.setClientMode(false)
    config.setConsistentId(java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getHostName)

    val ignite = Ignition.start(config)
    ignite.active(true)
```

Various files are created in those directories:

```
ignitedb/
├── storage
│   └── imac_home
│       ├── cache-changes
│       │   ├── 1113bbb3-6183-4f97-8783-ca61c4afffb0
│       │   │   ├── cache_data.dat
│       │   │   └── index.bin
│       │   └── 605e79c8-63aa-49d5-86b2-68468e648375
│       │       ├── cache_data.dat
│       │       └── index.bin
│       ├── cache-ignite-sys-cache
│       ├── cache-pings
│       │   ├── 86d44085-3eca-4dfa-92fb-c2e7fd0f4f4b
│       │   │   ├── cache_data.dat
│       │   │   ├── index.bin
│       │   │   └── part-714.bin
│       │   └── f69da997-fae5-45a5-9abc-44639bb46e8e
│       │       ├── cache_data.dat
│       │       ├── index.bin
│       │       ├── part-142.bin
│       │       ├── part-152.bin
│       │       ├── <many more>
│       ├── cache-products
│       │   ├── 1113bbb3-6183-4f97-8783-ca61c4afffb0
│       │   │   ├── cache_data.dat
│       │   │   ├── index.bin
│       │   │   ├── part-49.bin
│       │   │   ├── part-50.bin
│       │   │   ├── <many more>
│       │   └── 605e79c8-63aa-49d5-86b2-68468e648375
│       │       ├── cache_data.dat
│       │       ├── index.bin
│       │       └── part-49.bin
│       ├── cacheGroup-default-ds-group
│       │   ├── ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-ds-groupcache_data.dat
│       │   ├── index.bin
│       │   ├── part-264.bin
│       │   └── part-791.bin
│       ├── cp
│       │   ├── 1512524465868-cecd4b2e-5c0f-4b25-8ede-92336ba2aac3-END.bin
│       │   ├── 1512524465868-cecd4b2e-5c0f-4b25-8ede-92336ba2aac3-START.bin
│       │   ├── 1512524645873-70f73379-5e49-4779-849c-e1dda08e2f84-END.bin
│       │   ├── 1512524645873-70f73379-5e49-4779-849c-e1dda08e2f84-START.bin
│       │   ├── <many more>
│       └── lock
└── wal
    ├── archive
    │   └── imac_home
    └── imac_home
        ├── 0000000000000000.wal
        ├── 0000000000000001.wal
        ├── <many more>
```

However, when I stop and restart my application, all my caches have disappeared. How do I actually persist them to disk? Do I need to do something per-cache as well as enabling persistence globally? (The docs don't mention anything like that.)

I'm getting this exception at startup, which on closer inspection looks like it's coming from the persistence layer:

```
09:44:33.034 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.f.FilePageStoreManager - Resolved page store work directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home
09:44:33.034 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Resolved write ahead log work directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/wal/imac_home
09:44:33.034 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Resolved write ahead log archive directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/wal/archive/imac_home
09:44:33.044 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Started write-ahead log manager [mode=DEFAULT]
Can't load log handler "org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLoggerFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$5.run(LogManager.java:965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.loadLoggerHandlers(LogManager.java:958)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.initializeGlobalHandlers(LogManager.java:1578)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$1500(LogManager.java:145)
    at java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger.accessCheckedHandlers(LogManager.java:1667)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.getHandlers(Logger.java:1776)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.findHandler(JavaLogger.java:399)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.configure(JavaLogger.java:229)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.<init>(JavaLogger.java:170)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.<init>(JavaLogger.java:126)
    at org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcDriver.<clinit>(IgniteJdbcDriver.java:410)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.access$700(ServiceLoader.java:323)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$2.run(ServiceLoader.java:407)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:409)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:603)
    at java.sql.DriverManager$2.run(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.loadInitialDrivers(DriverManager.java:583)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.<clinit>(DriverManager.java:101)
    at org.h2.Driver.load(Driver.java:155)
    at org.h2.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:41)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.start(IgniteH2Indexing.java:2027)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.start(GridQueryProcessor.java:240)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startProcessor(IgniteKernal.java:1870)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:955)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1909)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1652)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1080)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:600)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:525)
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:322)
    at io.livefeeds.api.Main$.startIgnite(Main.scala:78)
    at io.livefeeds.api.Main$.main(Main.scala:25)
    at io.livefeeds.api.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:67)
    at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:61)
    at sbt.Run.sbt$Run$$execute$1(Run.scala:51)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Run$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Run.scala:55)
    at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
    at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The rest of the log output for persistence is:

```
09:44:34.682 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.f.FilePageStoreManager - Resolved page store work directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home
09:44:34.682 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Resolved write ahead log work directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/wal/imac_home
09:44:34.682 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Resolved write ahead log archive directory: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/wal/archive/imac_home
09:44:34.682 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Started write-ahead log manager [mode=DEFAULT]
09:44:34.747 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.p.PageMemoryImpl - Started page memory [memoryAllocated=6.4 GiB, pages=1634272, tableSize=94.9 MiB, checkpointBuffer=1.6 GiB]
09:44:34.785 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Read checkpoint status [startMarker=/Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home/cp/1512571436282-f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6-START.bin, endMarker=/Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home/cp/1512571307494-690bb0bf-e75e-4877-a3e5-ba7b43b190bd-END.bin]
09:44:34.786 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Checking memory state [lastValidPos=FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOffset=8996738, len=20281, forceFlush=false], lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOffset=9076734, len=20281, forceFlush=false], lastCheckpointId=f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6]
09:44:34.786 WARN  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Ignite node stopped in the middle of checkpoint. Will restore memory state and finish checkpoint on node start.
[09:44:34] Ignite node stopped in the middle of checkpoint. Will restore memory state and finish checkpoint on node start.
09:44:34.846 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Found last checkpoint marker [cpId=f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6, pos=FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOffset=9076734, len=20281, forceFlush=false]]
09:44:34.853 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Finished applying memory changes [changesApplied=8, time=65ms]
09:44:34.857 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Checkpoint finished [cpId=f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6, pages=6, markPos=FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOffset=9076734, len=20281, forceFlush=false], pagesWrite=-3ms, fsync=0ms, total=-3ms]
09:44:34.861 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.w.FileWriteAheadLogManager - Resuming logging to WAL segment [file=/Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/wal/imac_home/0000000000000000.wal, offset=9097015, ver=1]
09:44:35.065 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Started cache [name=ignite-sys-cache, memoryPolicyName=sysMemPlc, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL]
09:44:35.085 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor - Started cache [name=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-ds-group, group=default-ds-group, memoryPolicyName=default, mode=PARTITIONED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL]
09:44:35.087 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.d.d.p.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Successfully activated caches [nodeId=f616a68d-e171-4384-8dc4-45c2e6788afc, client=false, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=1]]
09:44:35.091 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.d.d.p.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture - Finished waiting for partition release future [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=1], waitTime=0ms, futInfo=NA]
09:44:35.139 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Read checkpoint status [startMarker=/Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home/cp/1512571436282-f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6-START.bin, endMarker=/Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home/cp/1512571436282-f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6-END.bin]
09:44:35.140 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Applying lost cache updates since last checkpoint record [lastMarked=FileWALPointer [idx=0, fileOffset=9076734, len=20281, forceFlush=false], lastCheckpointId=f25aee22-0e9e-4737-a0ad-aebc3c5a4bd6]
09:44:35.187 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Finished applying WAL changes [updatesApplied=0, time=51ms]
09:44:35.189 INFO  o.a.i.i.p.c.p.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager - Finished indexes rebuilding for cache: [name=ignite-sys-cache, grpName=null
```

Comment: Your configuration seems to be correct. And persistence files are written to the corresponding directory. Try enabling debug log for the following package: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence and looking for exceptions or errors.

Comment: Also make sure, that hostname, which is used as a consistent id, doesn't change between restarts.

Comment: @Denis I added the log output for persistence. It looks like that logging exception is coming from there. Could that be preventing it from working?

Comment: the exception is actually coming from registering of the H2 SQL driver. I don't see, why recovering data from persistence doesn't work. I'll let you know, if I have any ideas.

Comment: Are you sure Ignite is using correct directories as persistence files location? Do you have directories, corresponding to your caches, by this path: /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds/ignitedb/storage/imac_home/ ?

Comment: Yes, the `tree` in my question was run from /Users/dan/projects/livefeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `/` in my cache names were causing the persistence layer to create extra directories, because they're not escaped at all. I switched to using `@`, and it seems fine now.